How to resolve curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer wihtout settting network host or bind command
I want to run a flask test in docker container so run container in this way:
docker run -v ${SHARED_DIR}:/fiftyone -p 5151:5151 -p 5000:5000  -it voxel51/fiftyone:0.23.7-python3.8 /bin/bash 
and by installing flask and test a simple example

# save this as app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

Everything is OK inside docker container but I want to send request from host. To check:
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000
the response is :
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:5000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer



But I dont want to use docker run --network host option as indicated in Connection reset by peer when hitting Docker container or I don't want to run a command like this one as suggested by another user
docker run -p 8000:8000 -it python:3.7-slim python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0
Is there any way to that?

When I run it, it works fine. How do you run your application?

@HansKilian Everything is OK inside docker container, or when I do test send and receive in container.

I mean, how do you start the application inside the container after you've created the app.py file? What command do you use?

@HansKilian using a complex sample but I checked a simple one and both of them does not work.    from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"


Do you use flask run? You need to use flask run --host=0.0.0.0.

Not. I would be appreciate if you write the complete command. Should I set some variables in docker compose file to run  flask?

Your first docker run command shows you running the container in interactive mode. So flask run --host=0.0.0.0 is the complete command.
